# SQL syntax error near `logsBloom` when call web3.eth.sendTransaction

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, nodejs, mysql

When I am trying to call `web3.eth.sendTransaction` I receive this error stack:

```
Error: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' `logsBloom` = '0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000' at line 1
    at Query.Sequence._packetToError (/usr/lib/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Sequence.js:52:14)
    at Query.ErrorPacket (/usr/lib/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Query.js:77:18)
    at Protocol._parsePacket (/usr/lib/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:279:23)
    at Parser.write (/usr/lib/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Parser.js:76:12)
    at Protocol.write (/usr/lib/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:39:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:103:28)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:191:7)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:178:18)
    at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:136:10)
    at TCP.onread (net.js:561:20)
    --------------------
    at Protocol._enqueue (/usr/lib/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:145:48)
    at Connection.query (/usr/lib/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:208:25)
    at Query._callback (/usr/ico/_common/getMoneyGlobal.js:232:41)
    at Query.Sequence.end (/usr/lib/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Sequence.js:88:24)
    at Query._handleFinalResultPacket (/usr/lib/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Query.js:139:8)
    at Query.OkPacket (/usr/lib/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Query.js:72:10)
    at Protocol._parsePacket (/usr/lib/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:279:23)
    at Parser.write (/usr/lib/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Parser.js:76:12)
    at Protocol.write (/usr/lib/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:39:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:103:28)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:191:7)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:178:18)
    at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:136:10)
    at TCP.onread (net.js:561:20)
```

Maybe somebody met the same problem and knows how to fix it.

Thanks!